# Spring SecurityContext returning null authentication

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring Security for user authentication , but the SecurityContext is null when the user is not logged in.

In my **web.xml** I have:

```
 <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

In my **security.xml** I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:http="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- Static resources such as CSS and JS files are ignored by Spring Security -->
    <security:http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />

    <security:http use-expressions="true">
        <!-- Enables Spring Security CSRF protection -->
        <security:csrf/>
        <!-- Configures the form login -->
        <security:form-login
                login-page="/login"
                login-processing-url="/login/authenticate"
                authentication-failure-url="/login?error=bad_credentials"
                username-parameter="username"
                password-parameter="password"/>
        <!-- Configures the logout function -->
        <security:logout
                logout-url="/logout"
                logout-success-url="/home"
                delete-cookies="JESSIONID"/>

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" method="GET" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/user/register" method="POST" access="permitAll"/>

        <!-- These operations are protected. -->
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/product/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
        <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/login"/>

        <!-- Adds social authentication filter to the Spring Security filter chain. -->
        <security:custom-filter ref="socialAuthenticationFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    </security:http>
```

... other config...

The code where I am getting null is:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
SecurityContext securityContext =(SecurityContext) session.getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT");
Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();
user = (Object) authentication.getPrincipal();
```

But I am getting null  **securityContext** when no user is logged in. Any help where I am doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/anonymous.html:

> ...Note that there is no real conceptual difference between a user who is “anonymously authenticated” and an unauthenticated user. **Spring Security's anonymous authentication just gives you a more convenient way to configure your access-control attributes**. Calls to servlet API calls such as **getCallerPrincipal, for example, will still return null** even though there is actually an anonymous authentication object in the SecurityContextHolder.
>
> There are other situations where anonymous authentication is useful, such as when an auditing interceptor queries the SecurityContextHolder to identify which principal was responsible for a given operation. **Classes can be authored more robustly if they know the SecurityContextHolder always contains an Authentication object, and never null.**

So a setup like (also from cited page):

```
<bean id="anonymousAuthFilter"
  class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter">
  <property name="key" value="foobar"/>
  <property name="userAttribute" value="anonymousUser,ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
</bean>
<bean id="anonymousAuthenticationProvider"
  class="org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider">
  <property name="key" value="foobar"/>
</bean>
```

..and adjusting your security.xml entries from:

```
permitAll
```

..to:

```
ROLE_ANONYMOUS
```

should provide you always with a `Securitycontext`/`Authentication` object (but not necessarily with a "Principal").